# Does AND function work with text?

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to use AND function to evaluate if some criteria is met.

Cell G2=AMAZON_US, 
cell R2 = FBA,

my formula goes like this

=AND(G2="AMAZON_US", R2="FBA"),

but the result I getting is False, should be true. 
Any help will be appreciated

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your AND formula is correct, I tried and it returned true to me. I am wondering if your cell values are correct, i.e., if there are white-spaces in the cell content, or, you are referring to the correct cell values. Just to rule out for white spaces, can you try the following formula to see what happens?

```
=AND(TRIM(G2)="AMAZON_US",TRIM(R2)="FBA")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `EXACT` feature:

```
=AND(EXACT(G2,"AMAZON_US"), EXACT(R2,"FBA"))
```

This will do the string comparison.  This is a case sensitive comparison, so be careful.